# ^WJ can not split and open new window in my vim

Tags: vi

it is said that ^WJ splits the window and opens a window above the current window.
when i input :CTRL+WJ,no action of splits the window and opens a window happen in my vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL+W+J does not split your window and "creates" and opens a new window. Rather, it helps you in moving across multiple windows which might be open on your screen.

`CTRL+W` commands are simply for moving across multiple windows, which you might have open

`CTRL+W+J` will move one "window" down in the list of open windows

You can refer to [this](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442415-vim-tips-using-viewports) article for more on VIM commands for moving windows